# Reference for proof of correspondence between rational maps $X\dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ and linear system of divisors with no fixed component.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would like to ask if there is a reference for the following theorem somewhere in Harthorne:

Theorem. Let $X$ be a normal (usually, projective) variety. Then there is a one-to-one correspondence between

$$
\frac{\left\{\text { rational maps } X\dashrightarrow\mathbb{P}^n\right\}}{\text { (projective change of coordinates })} \longleftrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{c}
n \text {-dimensional linear systems of divisors on } \\
X \text { with no fixed component }
\end{array}\right\}
$$

So the thing is that I don't know enough scheme theory yet, so as I was browsing through Hartshorne, I'm not sure if I am actually looking at the scheme theoretic version of the theorem. May I ask if this theorem is actually proven in Hartshorne's text? If not, is there another text where I can find a proof? And a scheme theoretic version is fine.

Comment: I don't think this exact result is in there, but most of the important building blocks are. Would you be interested in seeing how to put the pieces together, or are you only interested in a citation to the full proof?

Comment: @KReiser ,  i am interested in knowing how we can prove this given all the preliminary results in Hartshorne if you can provide some hints, but at the moment, I actually need a reference for the full proof I can use for citation